# Python importing package as if it is a module

Tags: python, scanpy

I've been having a lot of trouble importing a package in Python called "scanpy" - I've been trying to follow this tutorial here (https://scanpy-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pbmc3k.html) but Python seems to view "scanpy" as a module of a package rather than a packge itself:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scanpy as sc
```

```
sc.settings.verbosity = 3
sc.logging.print_header()
sc.settings.set_figure_params(dpi=80, facecolor='white')
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-129af3139565> in <module>
----> 1 sc.settings.verbosity = 3
      2 sc.logging.print_header()
      3 sc.settings.set_figure_params(dpi=80, facecolor='white')

AttributeError: module 'scanpy' has no attribute 'settings'
```

Other people seem to have also had trouble installing "scanpy," so I followed kleurless's installation instructions on this GitHub thread (https://github.com/theislab/scanpy/issues/990). This is the result of those installation instructions. (Separately, I've also followed the installation instructions on the "scanpy" website but those didn't seem to work.) I'm also running the above lines of code in a Jupyter Notebook if that matters. I forgot to load the virtual environment before I loaded the Jupyter Notebook so I included "!source activate scanpy_environment" before the first line but that didn't help. If someone could help me, I would be extremely grateful.

Comment: packages *are modules*, which contain *submodules*. That is it.

Comment: Anyway, what version of `scanpy` are you using? This may be related: https://github.com/theislab/scanpy-tutorials/issues/1

Comment: By any chance, is there a file called `scanpy.py` in your working directory? i.e. if you do `!ls` in your jupyter notebook?

Comment: Thanks for your comments @juanpa.arrivillaga, I'm not quite sure what version of "scanpy" it is - I tried "sc.__version__" but that didn't return anything. I also tried "!conda list" but "scanpy" didn't appear there, so I'm not quite sure if my virtual environment activated properly

Comment: Standard debugging for problems like this: `print(sc.__file__)` to see exactly where the module is coming from, `print(dir(sc))` to see what's actually in it.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I don't see "scanpy.py" unfortunately

Comment: Thanks for your comment @jasonharper, I tried "print(sc.__file__)" but that returned "None" - I also tried "print(dir(sc))" and that returned "['__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']"

Comment: @jasonharper based on "print(dir(sc))," do you think "scanpy" has been properly imported?

Comment: Open a plain Python shell (not jupyter inside the browser) in a different directory, rerun and test it. If it still fails, give us the debugging information above.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed this on my backup test ubuntu computer and it works.
[image]

I did:
`pip install scanpy` in the bash terminal
then once it was installed I wrote this test script and ran it:

```
import scanpy as sc

sc.settings.verbosity = 3
sc.logging.print_header()
sc.settings.set_figure_params(dpi=80, facecolor='white')

print(sc.settings.verbosity)
print("test")
```

If it works, then it could be an issue with Jupyter notebook.

I would also say to check your modules by using `pip freeze` to see if scanpy is installed.